# nginx reverse proxy - doesn't close upstream connection when HTTPS client disconnects

Tags: nginx, https

I have a server which needs to know when the client closes the connection. The server is behind an nginx reverse proxy. Everything works fine over HTTP, but as soon as I turn SSL on, nginx seems to hold the upstream connection open for a full minute after the HTTPS client has disconnected.

How can I get nginx to close the upstream connection when the client disconnects?

Here's my nginx config:

```
ssl_session_cache off;
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key server.key;
  location /find {
    proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `proxy_ignore_client_abort on`. Prevents aborting request to proxy in case the client itself aborts the request

Comment: that is exactly the behaviour I *don't* want. I want the proxy to abort the upstream connection as soon as the client closes the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite late but might be helpful for others. I had the same problem and it turned out to be an issue with nginx (see https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4412004):

> So the underlying problem is that the nginx stream layer abstraction
>   isn't clean enough to handle low level OS events and then map them
>   through the SSL layer to read/write/eof conceptual events as needed.
>   Instead you need an OS level "eof" event, which you then assume maps
>   through the SSL abstraction layer to a SSL stream eof event.
>
> Ok, so I had a look at the kqueue eof handling, and what's needed for
>   epoll eof handling, and created a quick patch that seems to work.

I applied the [patch](http://robm.fastmail.fm/downloads/nginx-epoll-eof.patch) on 1.4.2 and it worked! No problems so far. Hopefully it will be fixed in one of the next releases.

**Edited**

This problem seems to be solved with nginx version >=**1.5.5**:

> Feature: now nginx uses EPOLLRDHUP events to detect premature connection close by clients if the "epoll" method is used.